# fopen error: failed to open stream: Is a directory

Tags: php, post, nginx, fopen

I've reviewed all similar questions and answers here but didn't find anything helpful for me :( I need to store file, I have a code that 100% works but when I try to upload big file (actually not very big - 2.5MB) I'm getting an error

```
(1/1) ErrorException
fopen(/home/user/Projects/foobar/public): failed to open stream: Is a directory
```

This problem is 100% due to file size (not with path or name because I can successfully upload another files from the same directory) because I've already tried to change permissions, moved content to new file but it didn't help.

Also I've changed nginx

```
client_max_body_size 100m;
```

and PHP configuration

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Comment: Did you reload your php nginx config ? e.g. service php5-fpm reload and
service nginx reload

Comment: Make a `info.php` with call to `phpinfo();` function and see if you see a different limit than you specified

Comment: @Sorin yea, sure, reload it each time I make any changes

Answer (score 5):

I was developing on the local server using angular 5 and Laravel running locally on 127.0.0.1:8000 and I was experiencing the same error when trying to upload files larger than 2M. I don't know about nginx but here is how I solved my error:

1. In my `etc/php/7.1` folder there is `cli` and `apache2`, both of which have `php.ini`. Changing `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in the php.ini inside apache2 alone did not solve the error. Then I realized that since I was running laravel from php artisan serve, cli might have something to do with it.
2. Finally, I also opened php.ini inside the cli folder and made changes to `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`, restarted apache2 by running

   `sudo service apache2 restart`

Then quit php artisan server and ng server and restarted them. Now everything works fine!

This might help somebody out there with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I was downloading a file from Google Cloud Storage bucket to my local storage and encountered the same problem.

> fopen(/var/www/test/files): Failed to open stream: Is a directory

I corrected the error by entering the full destination to save the object

> $destination = '/var/www/test/files/sap_data.csv';

I hope it will help you.